# Bootstrap validation feedback not displaying when using input groups with floating labels

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, user-interface, frontend

I found out that it is possible to combine floating labels with input groups. However, I cannot figure out how to get the feedback to display properly.

```html
<div class="input-group has-validation">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input name="token" placeholder="Enter your admin token" type="password" class="form-control is-valid"
            value="some token" />
        <label>Access Token</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Log in</button>
    <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
</div>
```

The bootstrap CSS for the valid-feedback just says:

```css
.valid-feedback {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0.25rem;
    font-size: .875em;
    color: var(--bs-form-valid-color);
}
```

Why would I want to have display set to none here?

When I am just using input groups without floating labels this seems to work fine. I am using the latest version of bootstrap (v5.3.2)